# How to implement a move constructor for a diamond-shaped inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I have a diamond-shaped hierarchy of classes, where there is no default constructor, nor copy constructors. The two constructors I have are a "move" one and another that takes a lvalue reference to an object:

```
struct base {
    base(base&&) = default;
    base(member_type&& m): member_(std::move(m)) {}
    member_type member_;
};

struct virt_1: virtual base {
    virt_1(virt_1&& rhs): base(std::move(rhs)) {}
    virt_1(member_type&& m): base(std::move(m)) {}
};

struct virt_2: virtual base {
    virt_2(virt_2&& rhs): base(std::move(rhs)) {}
    virt_2(member_type&& m): base(std::move(m)) {}
};

struct concrete: virt_1, virt_2 {
    concrete(concrete&& rhs) // ???
};
```

Besides not using a diamond-shaped hierarchy, is it possible to implement the move constructor for the concrete class?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds very error prone to me.  The constructor of the virtual base is called from the most derived class, and there should be no reason why it couldn't call a move constructor.  But any further derivation, and there's a good chance someone will forget it, or do it wrong.  As a general rule, virtual base classes shouldn't contain data, or at least have any constructors other than a default constructor, to avoid such problems.

Comment: @JamesKanze I am well aware that `base` should not contain data, or at least have a default constructor, but it cannot be the case in my context. However, is there any chance that the compiler will complain if someone forgets to call the virtual base constructor when deriving further?

Comment: @piwi, no, there is no chance, because `base` has no default constructor, so the most-derived type **must** construct it explicitly

Comment: @JamesKanze I have to admit that "breaking" the diamond shape is possible, but will require lots of work. As people pointed out regarding the "useless-ness" of the calls to the initializers, which I was not aware of/did not understand before, I will have to prospect this solution of avoiding this hierarchy :-/ Thanks

Comment: @piwi It's just a general rule.  I'm sure that there are legitimate exceptions.  As long as the virtual base class has *no* default constructors, you should get a compiler error if someone derives and doesn't mention in in the initializer list.  (Or... make all of the base class constructors private, and your derived class a friend, and no one can derive from your derived class.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with asking the compiler to provide the implementation?

```
concrete(concrete&&) = default;
```

I'd define the `virt_1` and `virt_2` move constructors as defaulted too.

You could write it out if you really wanted to:

```
concrete(concrete&& rhs)
: base(std::move(rhs)), virt_1(std::move(rhs)), virt_2(std::move(rhs))
{ }
```

Or if you really like typing:

```
    concrete(concrete&& rhs)
    : base(static_cast<base&&>(rhs)),
      virt_1(static_cast<virt_1&&>(rhs)),
      virt_2(static_cast<virt_2&&>(rhs))
    { }
```

The initializers for the `virt_1` and `virt_2` bases are useless, because they only call the `base` constructor and as it's a virtual base they won't do that when `concrete` has called it, but due to your choices of constructors you can't default-construct them and are required to initialize them with an rvalue even though they'll do nothing with it.

Comment: Question: wouldn't this be dangerous? Seems like it's moving multiple times from the same object...

Comment: I think that my problem lies in both constructors of the concrete class; I'll prospect with the default move constructor

Comment: @AndyProwl, no, see the last paragraph I added. The `base` constructor will only be called once (by the constructor for the most derived type) so all the other constructors don't actually do anything with their rvalue parameter. There will only be one move (remember that calling `std::move` doesn't actually move anything, a move only happens when something accepts an rvalue parameter and chooses to move from it.)

Comment: You are right, better let the compiler take care of the situation for me; thanks!

Comment: Actually, I am trying to understand the useless-ness of the initializers for `virt_1` and `virt_2`; What do you mean by "they won't do that" in "[virt_1 and virt_2] only call the base constructor and as it's a virtual base they won't do that when concrete has called it"? Are the initializers even called but the resulting behavior is somewhat discarded, or are the calls completely skipped in this case? Thanks.

Comment: The calls to `base(std::move(rhs))` are skipped in all constructors except the ones for the most-derived class, see [class.base.init]/7: "A _mem-initializer_ where the _mem-initializer-id_ denotes a virtual base class is ignored during execution of a constructor of any class that is not the most derived class."

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Any constructor with a `virtual` base somewhere in the hierarchy is responsible for initializing that base. Essentially any class below the `virtual` base in the hierarchy inherits permission to initialize the base.

In this case, the default move constructor should do the right thing. I would recommend also specifying `concrete : private virtual base` to clarify what's happening.

[Here](http://ideone.com/ri5P0a) is a working demo.

Comment: Might as well test the move assignment operator as well.

Comment: The class doesn't have to inherit directly from the base.  But it _is_ responsible for calling the constructors of any virtual bases, even if it doesn't inherit from them.

Comment: @JamesKanze Oh, I thought it was a syntax error to have a mem-initializer for an indirect base. It's not. Still, correct me if I'm wrong, but the difference is only syntax/style. It would make no difference to inherit from the base as well, and be illegal to inherit from the base without `virtual`.

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, I have a problem with the value that ends up in `b.member_` (http://ideone.com/3SDYH4); am I wrong somewhere with the modifications I made to your example?

Comment: @piwi I "implemented" the base move constructor to print a message but didn't actually make it initialize anything. Just make it assign a value.

Comment: @Potatoswatter It's not an error _if_ the base occurs as a virtual base somewhere in the hierarchy.  It's also not an error if you inherit non-virtually from the base, but in that case, you'd better have default constructors, because any attempt to cite the base in the initialization list will be ambiguous.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks for the review. The language holds up to a point against increasingly ludicrous demands. Disambiguating syntax would probably be possible but just encourage abuse.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that while the initializers of `virt_1` and `virt_2` are needed (since there is no default constructor), they are useless...